# how to hide the validation message on click of the textbox in asp.net mvc?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, model-view-controller

when i am trying to hide the validation message onclick of the textbox it is not hiding could you please help me out

```
<div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control", @autocomplete = "off", onclick = "clearValidation()" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email, "", new { @style = "color:white; font-weight:normal; margin-left:-155px;" })
                </div>


<script>

function clearValidation() {
            document.getElementsByClassName("validation-summary-errors").style.color = "#ff0000";
        }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this-

```
$.fn.clearValidation= function () {
    $(this).each(function() {
        $(this).find(".field-validation-error").empty();
        $(this).trigger('reset.unobtrusiveValidation');
    });
};
```

Comment: mark as answer if it worked else let me know @rajanikanth.

Comment: use this function like-  onkeydown="clearValidation();"